# What value is there in separating outbound vs. inbound credential usage in a TLS API?

Tags: tls, openssl, api, sspi

OpenSSL defines an [`SSL_CTX`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CTX_new.html) struct which can be [charged](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey.html) with (client or server) identities. If you pass it to [`SSL_connect`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_connect.html), you're a client; if you pass it to [`SSL_accept`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_accept.html), you're a server.

With SSPI/SChannel on Windows it appears that you're not allowed to wait that late to decide if you're a client or a server. In order to load certificates in the first place, you must first [`AcquireCredentialsHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acquirecredentialshandle--schannel), and decide between `SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND` (server) or `SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND` (client).

Is Microsoft's approach intrinsically any more secure than OpenSSL's? Is such an answer X.509-specific, i.e. does this have to do with SSPI and/or SChannel supporting security processes besides TLS?